# Allowing cross-origin requests for Android WebView

Tags: android, html, cross-domain, android-webview

I'm attempting to retrieve some data from my server, which is hosted at www.myURL.com/somefolder/runScript. I am serving up a webpage at www.myURL.com, which happens to be on the same server as the endpoint to retrieve my data. However, I am receive this error in eclipse:

```
08-03 19:47:57.210: E/Web Console(27287): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:myendpoint Origin http://www.myURL.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1
```

Has anybody successfully been able to allow cross-origin requests on an android webview? Thanks very much!

Comment: I've tried JSONP but I don't really like how you can't receive any kind of debug statements from the server...

Comment: can I achieve this using a javascriptinerface?

Comment: where exactly are you executing this???(android emulator???)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the correct header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on your server?

Have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know what exactly you want to do. Do you want to parse html documents?

you can have a look at jsoup from jsoup.org